# XML parsing for nested tags using python

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, nested-attributes

i would need a help on how to parse xml files with nested tags taking the user input as attribute value of a particular tag.

for eg:

if xml code has 12 mappings and we want to select the below mapping name "m_IF1_TD_SALESORDER_STG_PR4_VBPA_BUSINESS_PARTNER" as user input and thereby printing the particular mapping details.

```
 <MAPPING NAME="m_IF1_TD_SALESORDER_STG_PR4_VBPA_BUSINESS_PARTNER" DESCRIPTION="Data Mapping for loading Sales Order Business Partners from the staging database for PR4." OBJECTVERSION="1" ISVALID="YES" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
                <TRANSFORMATION NAME="sq_STG_PR4_VBPA" DESCRIPTION="" TYPE="Source Qualifier" OBJECTVERSION="1" REUSABLE="NO" VERSIONNUMBER="1">
                    <TRANSFORMFIELD NAME="MANDT" DESCRIPTION="" DATATYPE="string" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="3" SCALE="0" PICTURETEXT="" DEFAULTVALUE="" EXPRESSION="MANDT" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL"/>
                    <TRANSFORMFIELD NAME="VBELN" DESCRIPTION="" DATATYPE="string" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="10" SCALE="0" PICTURETEXT="" DEFAULTVALUE="" EXPRESSION="VBELN" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL"/>
                    <TRANSFORMFIELD NAME="POSNR" DESCRIPTION="" DATATYPE="decimal" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="6" SCALE="0" PICTURETEXT="" DEFAULTVALUE="" EXPRESSION="POSNR" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL"/>
                    <TRANSFORMFIELD NAME="PARVW" DESCRIPTION="" DATATYPE="string" PORTTYPE="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION="2" SCALE="0" PICTURETEXT="" DEFAULTVALUE="" EXPRESSION="PARVW" EXPRESSIONTYPE="GENERAL"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [XML ElementTree module of python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

It is very simple to use. For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/filename.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for subchild in root.findall('subchildName'):
    print(subchild.get('subchildAttribute')
```

Comment: Hy...Yash thanks but this is not our exact requirement in my sample code we have 12 mappings and 20+ transformations within each mapping,the user input should be the transformation name and it should display all the attributes and child elements within that transformation name.